# How to remove a property from a css class in ionic framework?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to remove a property which was applied to a class by ionic.

```
.bar {
   border: none;
}
```

I don't want ionic to apply this `border` property to `bar` class. I tried `jquery` like

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery/src/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
```

before the closing body tag

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$('.bar').removeProp('border');
</script>
</body>
```

but it failed to recognize `$` (jquery).

Comment: made the jquery working it's `<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Have you tried by using removeAttribute.

Comment: I make it to work by setting empty value for background-image, which was the culprit behind this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the lastest CSS style you try to puy:

```
.bar {
   border: none !important;
}
```

nothing elese :-)

Comment: i want to remove the border property.. If I unselect the border propert which is et to none, I got the desired look

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by:

```
 $(".bar").css( 'border' : '' );
```